# Rename the generated foreign key column generated using custom Naming Strategy

Tags: jpa, hibernate-mapping, hyperjaxb

I want to change the name of the foreign key column generated by my Schema. Below is the schema configuration that I am using :

```
    <xs:complexType name="ActivityFact">
        <xs:sequence>
                    <!-- Other Element Declaration -->
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:long" />
    </xs:complexType>
```

When I run the this configuration , I got 2 tables :
1. ActivityDim
2. ActivityFact ( ActivityDim Id as a foreign key with name activityDim_ActivityFact_Id)

I want to change the above generated name to the schema element name which is actvitiyDim in this case. I am not sure how to use the custom naming Strategy. I have tried to override foreignKeyColumnName method , but didn't work

```
public class ForeignKeyNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ForeignKeyNamingStrategy.class);

    @Override
    public String foreignKeyColumnName(
            String propertyName, String propertyEntityName, String propertyTableName, String referencedColumnName
    ) {
        return  propertyName; 
    }
```

I have also given this class reference in my persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <persistence-unit name="reportingData">
        <!-- These properties are defined in persistence-model/src/main/resources/persistence.xml. 
            HyperJAXB3 merges them into its generated and final persistence.xml -->
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy"
                value="com.namingStrategy.ForeignKeyNamingStrategy" /></properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am new to Hibernate , my understanding could be a bit disconnected. Can someone please suggest ?

Comment: Do you want to change naming strategy for all your foreign keys or just for this particular one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of Hyperjaxb.

This is a preliminary answer, we'll probably need to refine it later on.

First of all, please show the full schema fragment with `ActivityDim` and `ActivityFact` as well as what's generated. Do you have a `many-to-one` or `many-to-many` or `one-to-many` relationship here?

Next, check the [customization guide](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Customization+Guide). As far as I understand your problem, you probably need to customize the name of the foreign key column. This should be possible OOTB without implementing a custom namin strategy. Assuming you have a `one-to-many` relationship here, this will be somewhere [here](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Customization+Guide#CustomizationGuide-Customizingtheone-to-manyproperty). This is the [relevant part of the ORM schema](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/schemas/persistence/src/main/resources/persistence/orm/orm_1_0.xsd#L1401-L1464) which is used for customizations. I think you need to customize the name of the `join-column` here so my guess would be something like:

```
        <hj:one-to-many>
            <orm:join-column name="actvitiyDim"/>
        </hj:one-to-many>
```

[Here's an example from one of the test projects](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/tests/cu-one/src/main/resources/schema.xsd#L44-L50):

```
        <xs:element name="one-to-many-join-column" type="test:two" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <hj:one-to-many>
                        <orm:join-column name="O2MJC_ONE_ID"/>
                    </hj:one-to-many>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
```

Probably quite close to your case.

Now, naming strategies.

Naming strategy has nothing to do with Hibernate or JPA. Naming strategy is a internal component which Hyperjaxb3 uses during schema compilation to generate names of tables, columns etc. So it's actually very low-level.

If you for some reason want a different naming, you can write and configure your own implementation of the naming strategy. See [this test project](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/tree/master/ejb/tests/custom-naming) for example. But it's no longer *customization*, it's already *extending* Hyperjaxb. You would basically *rewrite* a part of Hyperjaxb. For instance you could do this if you want to change how *all* of the FK names are generated by default. I'm not sure this is what you want here.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I am able to customize the foreign key column name. Is it also possible that I write one rule at only one place( my foreign key name to be similar as my schema element name ) . And It will be true for all the foreign keys generation?

Comment: @priyas If you want to customize FK names generation in general, then it's really a custom naming strategy. You'll probably need to override [this method](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/master/ejb/plugin/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hyperjaxb3/ejb/strategy/naming/impl/DefaultNaming.java#L238-L252).